# I prompt the user for a computer name during the WinPE phase of OSD

Tags: powershell, sccm, winpe

During the WinPE phase of an OSD Deployment, I launch a form for the user to enter a computer name. Part of the PS Script needs the ActiveDirectory Module imported however, I can't get the AD Module to import.

```
Import-Module (Join-Path $(Split-Path $env:SMS_ADMIN_UI_PATH) ConfigurationManager.psd1)
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
```

File Name Set-OSDComputerNamePrompt-TST.ps1

Below is one of the Array's I'm adding

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$ADSites = (Get-ADReplicationSite -filter *).Name
```

I have the PowerShell module added to the Boot.Wim file and I've copied the

[Prompt for Computer Name form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYEo8.png)

Comment: There several documents on the web how to [Add Active Directory PS Module to WinPE](http://www.osdnerd.com/?p=170), but I would recommend *not* use AD in PE but use the [Active Directory Service Interfaces (ADSI)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/active-directory-service-interfaces-adsi) instead to keep the ASD image lean. See e.g.: [Working with Active Directory using PowerShell ADSI adapter](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4231.working-with-active-directory-using-powershell-adsi-adapter.aspx)

Comment: iRon, thank you for the reply. I looked at the links and only the first one came close to working however, the "Install-Module ActiveDirectory" does not work on my systems.

Windows 10 1909
Windows Server 2016
ADK Win 1903

So I am not able to leverage the Import-Module ActiveDirectory so I can use the Get-ADReplicationSite commandlet. ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WinPE is not normal Windows and the Active Directory commandlets are very special (they need a setup to work on non server OS) so this is a bad combination.

As iRon commented there are ways to include this but those will always be an unsupported hack. If the PE Version changes it could be that it has to be done with different files or it could be that ne version just completely breaks the hack. You should not rely on something like this for OSD. (I don't know about your specific AD setup but for most of them it would be by far less work to hard code the domain names in the script and update the script on each site addition than to always keep up with the PE changes which are by design 3 times a year)

The fallback for all AD related stuff that works without the module would be adsi which can work in PE (for Powershell to work in general you have to alter the boot image but those changes are supported by SCCM so they provide no additional work on release changes and you probably already did that to come this far)

With adsi you can get a list of your sites like this:

```
$sitesDN = "LDAP://CN=Sites," + $([adsi] "LDAP://RootDSE").Get("ConfigurationNamingContext")
$ADSites = (([adsi]$sitesDN).psbase.children | where {$_.Objectclass -ieq "site"}).Name
```

As a side note: I assume you have different sites for this code to be needed. If this is one of those cases where this method would be the "gold standard" because it works regardless of AD setup but you personally only have one site that is not likely to change (like a lot of people probably have) I would advise against such a complicated solution even if it is fail safe and just hard code the name. PE has lots of special cases and is hard to debug sometimes so reduce complexity if possible (as long as it let's you keep the same convenience of course).